# Can't mass assign attributes in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got my knickers in a twist.  My aim is for anyone logged in to be able to edit a guideline.  The show action will then show updated_by and created_by users.  Something is not right.

guidelines_controller.rb

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
def update

    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @guideline.update_attributes(params[:guideline])
        @guideline.update_attribute(:updated_by, current_user.id)

def show
    @guideline = Guideline.find(params[:id])
    if @guideline.updated_by
     @updated = User.find(@guideline.updated_by).profile_name
   end

      if User.find(@guideline.user_id)
     @created = User.find(@guideline.user_id).profile_name
      end
```

guidelines.rb (MODEL)

```
 attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty, :updated_by, :current_user

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :favourite_guidelines
```

I do seem to be able to assign an updated_by correctly.  But when I go into admin and try to change a guideline user I get the error:

```
Processing by Admin::GuidelinesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x+2BC0ztrqLBasL5uWskDEdars+FvSSNRvzGJuXyiA0=", "guideline"=>{"user_id"=>"13", "title"=>"URL testing", "content"=>"http://www.healme.com", "hospital"=>"Children's Hospital", "subtitle"=>"", "specialty"=>"Cardiology", "slug"=>"", "updated_by"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Guideline", "id"=>"37-url-testing"}
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Guideline Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "guidelines".* FROM "guidelines" WHERE "guidelines"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "37-url-testing"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subtitle, slug):
```

Is this an issue with by before_filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate working solution would be to add `subtitle` and `slug` to the `attr_accessible` list.

Bear in mind that the user of your app will be able to update them even if the form does not contain fields for them, he can perfectly craft a query with the fields.

Fields that are not in the `attr_accessible` list must be assigned individually as follows :

```
@guideline.subtitle = ...
@guideline.slug = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right there in the error message:

`ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subtitle, slug):`

If you want to mass-assign these attributes, you will need to add them to your `attr_accessible` list in your model.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment for more details.

Answer (score 1):

add subtitle and slug to attr_accessible list.

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your model by putting the **subtitle and slug** in the `attr_accessible`.

guidelines.rb (MODEL)

```
 attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty, :updated_by, :current_user, :subtitle, :slug
```

**NOTE**: Putting any field in `attr_accessible` will allow any user to mass assign the attributes that you added either by form in a browser or by a code. So if you do then do it with caution keeping in mind that what fields you want to be mass assigned by any user and what fields you do not.